# Objective C iOS - Crossfade size transition for UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uiviewanimation

I am trying to make a custom UIView in which a label on the view starts as a two-line preview of text, then grows to the size of the text when the view is pulled down to make room for the bigger label. I want the transition to crossfade between the two sizes. If I set the frame inside the animation block, it animates with the label coming in from off-screen at the new size instead of just crossfading. If I put it in the completion block, it doesn't crossfade animate at all. I'm sure I am doing something dumb, here. Note that I am using transitionWithView in the example code below, but the same thing happens with animateWithDuration...

```
CGSize newSize = [self.label.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.label.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)
                                                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                 attributes:@{
                                                              NSFontAttributeName : self.label.font
                                                              }
                                                    context:nil].size;

CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(self.label.frame.origin.x, self.label.frame.origin.y, self.label.frame.size.width, newSize.height);

[UIView transitionWithView:self duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
        self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        self.label.frame = newRect;
        self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }];
```

Comment: I think the trick is to set the frame before the animation and just change `numberOfLines` in the animation block - Try this code - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/84fc8db04947552ce36d I created a UILabel subclass rather that a method in the view controller but you should be able to use it your way if you just change `self` to `self.label` where appropriate

Comment: Playing around a bit more - If I set the constraints so that the height of the label 'floated' then I didn't even need to explicitly change the frame, I just animated the change to `numberOfLines`

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that!